# Program Minecraft Mods without Changing Environment Variables?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am wanting to program Minecraft mods using forge.  I am going through the standard installation to begin creating mods, but I have run into an issue.  I ran the code "gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse" and it is telling me "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.  Please set the JAVA_Home vairable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation."  Is it possible to change something else or do something else that will allow me to program?  I also cant change the environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* change environment variables, even without being an administrator.

The easiest solution is to use `set` to temporarily change the environment variable for only your session (IE, it'll get reset when you close your command prompt):

```batch
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse
```

Obviously, you'd change the location given to a different one if you have the JDK in a different location.

If you want to change it more permanently, you can use the [setx](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx) command.  Setx keeps the changes you made between sessions (and, more importantly, you don't need to be an administrator, since changes are only made to your account).  Note that running setx doesn't apply the changes to the *current* command prompt window, only future ones; you'd need to close and reopen command prompt after setting the path.

Run

```batch
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91"
```

and then close and reopen your command prompt, and it should keep the path set.  (Note that again, you'd want to use the path for your java installation; also it needs to be surrounded by quotes here).

---

If you don't want to run `set` each time, you can probably edit `gradlew.bat` and put the same `set` command at the top of it.

Simply open `gradlew.bat` with a text editor and then put

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
```

at the top of it (again, replace the path with the correct one for your version).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  I will use this when I have the chance again.