# Setting up programming environment for minecraft 1.12 modding, running into gradle decompile error

Tags: java, environment-variables, minecraft, gradlew, java-home

So I'm following [this walkthrough here](https://techwiseacademy.com/minecraft-modding-setting-up-your-environment/) to setup Eclipse to mod Minecraft. When I run `gradlew setupDecompWorkspace --refresh-dependencies` it will run until it reaches the `:recompileMC` stage and fail with an error stating that my java_home classpath is set to the 1.8 JRE. However I've already changed it to point to the 13.0 JDK. Clearly there is some place that I'm missing that it's reading from. I even tried the solution in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869464/program-minecraft-mods-without-changing-environment-variables) and I still get the same error. Please see the image below.

[Error message and variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5O2X.jpg)

**EDIT:** Alright, well simply restarting my computer resolved that error but now I'm cursed with a new one. `Could not determine java version from 13.0.1`. I'm currently researching about this error and will update if I can't resolve it myself

**EDIT2:** So it turns out the previous error is caused by using a version of gradle incompatible with newer versions of the JDK. I tried downgrading to JDK10, something that was supported but received the same error. I tried upgrading gradle but the newer versions remove the setupDecompWorkspace command which seems to mean I cannot move forward on setting up a programming environment for MC 1.12. Funnily enough, gradle works fine when pointing to JRE 1.8 but cannot decompile because it's not a JDK, but can't "find a version" for the JDK and cannot run at all.

Comment: Just an idea since I have come across this problem myself: After setting the correct environment variable, have you tried to restart Eclipse?

Comment: Gave it a shot, unfortunately not. I think java_home is being defined by gradlew somewhere but I'm not sure where

Comment: I guess you have seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307516/gradle-finds-wrong-java-home-even-though-its-correctly-set

Comment: I read through it but not sure how to make it relevant to a windows environment. Gradle isn't actually installed, I'm using a wrapper, so there is no /user/bin/gradle to check line 70 with. I've checked the wrapper files around the /minecraftforge/ directory but everything's defined with $JAVA_HOME$ and nothing is explicitly defined | EDIT: Ok, my bad for not restarting the computer but that seemed to have worked. Now I get a new error haha, dang

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was supposed to be using java 1.8 JDK all along. Not the Java 9,10 etc JDK. All fixed